# Is there any addon for Visual Studio that enables drag-and-drop references?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, plugins, reference, add-in

I would like to drag a dll to my project references. Is it possible? Is there an plugin for it?

Comment: From windows explorer would be a nice thing

Comment: Or drag and drop a project from the solution explorer would also be nice

Answer (score 6):

[PowerCommands](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands/) allows you to copy/paste references. I don't think it supports drag 'n drop though

Comment: Nice feature. I already use PowerCommands but I didn't notice it until you posted this.

Answer (score 0):

I just did that yesterday. Expand the reference icon, open the windows explorer that contains the reference and then drag it into the expanded reference icon.

It worked.